# 1120:access of undefined property playWithTouch

Tags: actionscript-3

I think my code is ok, but for some odd reason it doesn't work properly.
I am new to this AS3 but trying my best to make it work.

```
package {
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.display.Stage;
  import flash.display.NativeMenu;
  import flash.display.NativeMenuItem;
  import flash.display.NativeWindow;
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
  import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;
  import flash.events.TimerEvent;
  import flash.ui.Keyboard;
  import flash.ui.Multitouch;
  import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
  import flash.system.System;
  import flash.desktop.SystemIdleMode;
  import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
  import flash.utils.Timer;


  public class Shooter extends MovieClip {
    private var welcomeScreenMC: Welcome = new Welcome();
    public function Shooter() {
      // constructor code
      stage.addChild(welcomeScreenMC);
      welcomeScreenMC.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
      welcomeScreenMC.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
      welcomeScreenMC.buttonMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playWithTouch);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So when `buttonMC` is clicked it must do the instructions found inside a function named `playWithTouch`... Problem is you don't have a `public function playWithTouch (event:EMouseEvent) : void {  /* instruction code here etc etc*/  }`.

Comment: @VC.One It does not necessarily has to be **public**.

Comment: And where is your playWithTouch function located, can you add it to the code?